# How to replace empty cells with 0 and change strings to integers where possible in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a 3000+ columns. Many cells in the dataframe are empty strings (' '). Also, I have a lot of numerical values that are are strings but should actually be integers. I wrote two functions to fill all the empty cells with a 0 and where possible change the value to an integer, but when I run them nothing changes to my dataframe. The functions:

```
def recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns):

    for column in list_of_columns:
        dataframe[column].replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
        dataframe[column].fillna(0)

    return dataframe

def change_string_to_int(dataframe, list_of_columns):

    dataframe = recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns)

    for column in list_of_columns:
        try:
            dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].astype(int)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return dataframe
```

Note: I'm using a try/except statement because some columns contain text in some form. Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:

Thanks to your help I got the first part working. All the empty cells have 0s now. This is my code at this moment:

```
def recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns):

    for column in list_of_columns:
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].replace(r'\s+', 0, regex=True)

    return dataframe

def change_string_to_int(dataframe, list_of_columns):

    dataframe = recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns)

    for column in list_of_columns:
        try:
            dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].astype(int)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return dataframe
```

However, this gives me the following error: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Comment: You could do `dataframe[list_of_columns].replace(r'\s+', 0, regex=True)` directly.

Comment: If a column generates any error when converting to string, you want to skip it entirely?

Comment: The other way around, if a column generates an error converting to integer I want to skip it. Those columns probably contain a string that should remain a string like columns with text in them.

Comment: Then I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: You probably have a very large `int` in there. You should skip that column too, by adding another error type in your except statement.

Comment: That worked perfectly!!!! Thank you IanS!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you are not saving your change in your function:

```
def recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns):

    for column in list_of_columns:
      dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
      dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].fillna(0)

    return dataframe
```

Comment: Awesome! All the blank cells are now 0s. Do get an error now on the second part: 'Python int too large to convert to C long'

Comment: what about the itegers?

Comment: df.replace(r'\s+',np.nan,regex=True).replace('',np.nan) will enable replacing empty cells too.

Answer (score 4):

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['2', 'hello'], B=['', '3']))
df
```

[image]

---

`apply`

```
def convert_fill(df):
    return df.stack().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').fillna(0).unstack()

convert_fill(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Problem is, blank strings like `' '` should be replaced by 0, and strings that fail to convert by `np.nan`. Here you replace all of them by 0.

Comment: hi, i like your convert_fill function, but in my case it was a column of object with blanks and numbers(as objects). when i run convert_fill, it changes every value to 0. how to retain those non-blank values?